# How to get unique records based on two fields Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I need to filter Home records based on uniq inspection_id

```
Home.all.select(:id,:inspection_id)

  [#<Home:0x007fc5cd065758 id: 2192, inspection_id: 21967>,
 #<Home:0x007fc5cd065618 id: 2191, inspection_id: 21968>,
 #<Home:0x007fc5cd0654d8 id: 2190, inspection_id: 21967>,
 #<Home:0x007fc5cd065398 id: 2189, inspection_id: 21968>,
 #<Home:0x007fc5cd065258 id: 2188, inspection_id: 21963>,
 #<Home:0x007fc5cd065118 id: 2187, inspection_id: 21967>]
```

Need the result like this

```
[#<Home:0x007fc5cd065758 id: 2192, inspection_id: 21967>,
     #<Home:0x007fc5cd065618 id: 2191, inspection_id: 21968>,
     #<Home:0x007fc5cd065118 id: 2188, inspection_id: 21963>]
```

Home with ids `2191,2191,2188` , I need in result set

I tried this , but not works.

```
Home.all.select(:id,:inspection_id).distinct
```

Gives this error

> Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'myDB.homes.created_at' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your RDBMS, but in PostgreSQL you can use [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```rb
Home.select('DISTINCT ON (inspection_id) *')
```

Comment: I am Using MySql

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think this is a valid SQL statement. DISTINCT will work on all the columns defined in SELECT clause and will return all records because ID will be different for all. The better option to use is GROUP.

`Home.all.select(:id, :inspection_id).group(:inspection_id)`
This will group all records by inspection_ids and if you call `to_a` on above query - you'll get only valid records. You can also iterate on above records.

Other option is that if you are not expecting many rows - just use `Home.all.pluck(:id, :inspection_id)` and do the unique logic on the rails side - but not a good solution if you have thousands and millions of rows - which will load all the records into memory.

Comment: Gives me this error when I tried with group. "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'myDB.homes.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Comment: Any other way to acheive the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Udit's code looks good but it needs some changes. Try the below code:

```
Home.all.order(: inspection_id, :id).select('DISTINCT ON (inspection_id) id, inspection_id')
```

Comment: Erro r" Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON (inspection_id) id, inspection_id "

Answer (score 0):

You could use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to mark the top record(order by id) each group by `inspection_id`, then just select those top records:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<~SQL
  SELECT w.id, w.inspection_id
  FROM(
    SELECT 
       id, inspection_id, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY inspection_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS row
    FROM homes
  ) w
  WHERE w.row = 1
SQL
```